# Performance difference between querying with key_name and a property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Assume I have the following entity kind:

```
class ExampleModel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

mdl = ExampleModel(key_name='blah', name='abcd')
mdl.put()
```

Is there any performance difference between

```
ExampleModel.get_by_key_name('blah')
```

and

```
ExampleModel.all().filter('name = ', 'abcd').get()
```

If there's a performance difference, how much is it (roughly)? How does `ExampleModel` having an index for `name` influence the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a performance (and price) difference.

In the query case you need to do 2 read operations:

- 1 lookup in the index table
- 1 lookup in the entity table

In the get_by_key case you only do 1 read operation:

- 1 lookup for the entity table

Also note that indexed property also affect write performance and cost, as you need to do 1 additional write in the index table for reach indexed propery.

Feel free to take a look at [this presentation](http://proppy-appstats.appspot.com/#3) about Datastore performance patterns and anti-patterns. By clicking the `Run` button on each side you can see the interactive appstats traces for each code snippets.